# From NSData to SecKeyRef in swift 2

Tags: swift, encryption, swift2, seckeyref

I have a public/private key pair generated with RSACryptor.swift
I am able to convert my public key into a base64 string to be stored on my server.

I want to retrieve the public key on an other iOS device and use it to encrypt a message.

I am able to convert the base64 key to an NSData

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: publicKeyBase64!, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

But I can't find how to convert it into a `SecKeyRef` so I can use it easily.

Answers I found were in Objectiv-C and outdated.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think to obtain your SecKeyRef you need to retrieve it from a keychain. So you maybe need to obtain a SecKeychainItemRef, which need to be created from a key chain.

For that, you can import your key to your keychain with SecItemImport:

[Converts an external representation of a keychain item or items into SecKeychainItem objects and optionally imports them into a specified keychain.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1395728-secitemimport)